# PHP Array Search to get the second result

Tags: php, arrays, performance

i got an Array like:

```
array(127) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "Info"
    [1]=>
    int(9) "28491231"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "description"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "Webserver"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "server_type"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "HOST"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "os"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "Windows"
  }
```

....

What would the fastest way to search for "Info" in this Array and get the Value "28491231" ?

Thanks

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with the actual question. Also, what you need is a very simple loop and an `if` condition with a `break`.

Comment: That array by itself will only offer linear search (what Sergiu said). If you want to have faster searches you will have to implement an additional data structure which functions as index. So please give more information about the requirements of your search. (Only the index field? How many millions of entries? Do you have more than a TB of RAM? ..)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an array like this:

```
$sourceArray = array(
    array('Info', '28491231'),
    array('description', 'webserver'),
    array('server_type', 'HOST'),
    array('os', 'Windows'),
);
```

i.e.

[image]

If you want to get something specific from it, you can create a helper function like this:

```
// Helper Function
function getData($targetKey, $sourceArray) {
    foreach ($sourceArray as $arrayItem) {
        list ($key, $val) = $arrayItem;
        if ($key == $targetKey)
            return $val;
    }
    return false;
}

// Usage
var_dump(getData('Info', $sourceArray));
```

Ouputs:

[image]